# Entity framework declaration produce error

Tags: entity-framework

I'm using VB.net 2013, Entity Framework 5.0 (`ObjectContext` model), SQL Server 2008R2 (database name `MyDB`, has one table `MyTable`)

I created `model.EDMX`, context name is `MyDBEntities1`

Now I want to declare a variable as entity:

```
Dim e as MyDBEntities1
```

But I get an error to `MyDBEntities1`. As solutions I get `"Import WindowsApplication1.MyDBModel"`

I have some previous projects, and the declaration is like I wrote.

What's the problem with this project ?

Thank you !

Comment: Well, you just need to import that namespace so that the `MyDbEntities1` class becomes "visible" and thus usable to your code!

Comment: In the beginning my project used DbContext model.And everything was ok. After I modify to Objectcontext , and after that I get this error.

Answer (score 0):

The application is not aware this model exists yet, because your entities reside in the folder `MyDBModel`.

If you want to use this entities file in a class, you need to tell the class, that there is stuff in that folder, which it can use

C# `using WindowsApplication1.MyDBModel`

VB `Imports WindowsApplication1.MyDBModel`

Alternatively you could write it this way:

```
Dim e as WindowsApplication1.MyDBModel.MyDBEntities1
```

Comment: I don't have any folder MyDBModel. In the beginning my project used DbContext model.And everything was ok. After I modify to Objectcontext , and after that I get this error.